# Angularjs issue with model binding with dropdown

Tags: angularjs

so i have a problem in setting the value in this dropdown:

```js
angular.module("myApp",[])
.controller("myController", function($scope){
$scope.selected_country = { value: "orig value" }
$scope.countries = [
  { id: 1, nicename: "Philippines", iso: "PH"},
  { id: 2, nicename: "United States", iso: "US"} 
]

$scope.load_states = function(){
  console.log('load states',$scope.selected_country);
  //do post request here to get states
}
});
```

```html
<html lang="en" ng-app="myApp">
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
    </head>
  <body ng-controller="myController">
<select ng-model="selected_country" ng-change="load_states()" id="country" name="country" class="form-control" ng-options="data as data.nicename for data in countries" required>
  <option value="">--Select--</option>
</select>
    <section>
    {{selected_country}}
    </section>
    </body>
</html>
```

i have this exact code in a project im working on.. on this example IT IS WORKING.. however in my code. i don't know why $scope.selected_country doesn't change when i console.log it. BUT when i print the selected_country ({{selected_country}}) in the html, i can see it changes value.. any idea why? i am grinding my teeth for hours now.

Comment: I don't know what your project look like but most probably the value from dropdown is set not on controller's scope. You can check this with Batarang or Angular Inspector for Chrome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess in your real code the dropdown is inside some other container that creates child scope. So your `selected_country` is not set on controller's own scope but on some control's scope. That's why you see it working here in snippet, but it doesn't work in your project. It's one of the reasons it's often recommended to use `controllerAs` syntax where you would refer to this variable as `vm.selected_country` and it would be in right scope.

You can create some container variable in controller (like `$scope.vm = {};`) and set `selected_country` on it. It should work.

```
<select ng-model="vm.selected_country" ng-change="load_states()" id="country" name="country" class="form-control" ng-options="data as data.nicename for data in countries" required>
```

But this is only to confirm the issue as using `controllerAs` is more of architectural decision.

----- EDIT ------

Look at the edited snippet below (run it), you will see that with child scope it doesn't work anymore.

```js
angular.module("myApp",[])
.controller("myController", function($scope){
$scope.selected_country = { value: "orig value" }
$scope.countries = [
  { id: 1, nicename: "Philippines", iso: "PH"},
  { id: 2, nicename: "United States", iso: "US"} 
]

$scope.load_states = function(){
  console.log('load states',$scope.selected_country);
  //do post request here to get states
}
});
```

```html
<html lang="en" ng-app="myApp">
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
    </head>
  <body ng-controller="myController">
<div ng-if="true"> <!-- create child scope -->
<select ng-model="selected_country" ng-change="load_states()" id="country" name="country" class="form-control" ng-options="data as data.nicename for data in countries" required>
  <option value="">--Select--</option>
</select>
</div>
    <section>
    {{selected_country}}
    </section>
    </body>
</html>
```

And now with `vm` variable it works again despite child scope:

```js
angular.module("myApp",[])
.controller("myController", function($scope){
$scope.vm = {};
$scope.vm.selected_country = { value: "orig value" }

$scope.countries = [
  { id: 1, nicename: "Philippines", iso: "PH"},
  { id: 2, nicename: "United States", iso: "US"} 
]

$scope.load_states = function(){
  console.log('load states',$scope.vm.selected_country);
  //do post request here to get states
}
});
```

```html
<html lang="en" ng-app="myApp">
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
    </head>
  <body ng-controller="myController">
<div ng-if="true"> <!-- create child scope -->
<select ng-model="vm.selected_country" ng-change="load_states()" id="country" name="country" class="form-control" ng-options="data as data.nicename for data in countries" required>
  <option value="">--Select--</option>
</select>
</div>
    <section>
    {{vm.selected_country}}
    </section>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: hhmm.. the dropdown is inside uib-tab (angular-ui) and the dropdown coutries values as set from another post request where i get all the countries.

Comment: Check this with Angular Inspector. Your `selected_country` variable is not set on controller's scope. That's why it cannot `console.log` it's value because it's in child scope. And Angular only searches variables in parents.

Comment: @GelBalano Look at examples I added. They show what's happening and also show how to solve the issue.

Comment: you sire saved me!! this works! guess setting an angular foreach inside UI-tab is considered inside child scope. many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try This
`$scope.selected_country = { id: 1, nicename: "Philippines", iso: "PH"}`

`$scope.selected_country` type should be the same as object of `$scope.countries`

Comment: I did use the same format but the console log in load_states() always log its value. not the new one. :(

Comment: Can you create plunker?

Answer (score 0):

```js
angular.module("myApp",[])
.controller("myController", function($scope){
$scope.countries = [
  { id: 0, value: "--Select--", iso: "OV"},
  { id: 1, value: "Philippines", iso: "PH"},
  { id: 2, value: "United States", iso: "US"} 
];
$scope.selected_country = $scope.countries[0];

$scope.load_states = function(val){
  $scope.selected_country = val;
  console.log('load states',$scope.selected_country);
  //do post request here to get states
}
});
```

```html
<html lang="en" ng-app="myApp">
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
    </head>
  <body ng-controller="myController">
<select ng-model="selected_country" ng-change="load_states(selected_country)" id="country" name="country" class="form-control" ng-options="data as data.value for data in countries track by data.id" required>
</select>
    <section>
    {{selected_country}}
    </section>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: structure of selected object should be like this.

$scope.selected = $scope.items[0];
Sources: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions

Comment: this works however i cant set the value back to the select dropdown. (two way binding isnt working). does my problem makes sense? lol

Answer (score 0):

Modify your code as below:

```
  $scope.countries = [{
    id: 1,
    nicename: "Philippines",
    iso: "PH"
  }, {
    id: 2,
    nicename: "United States",
    iso: "US"
  }];

  $scope.selected_country = $scope.countries[0];
```

This will work.

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/shashank2691/22ky6e3q/)

Comment: I use the first value (index 0) as initial value but the console log in load_states() always log the initial value not the new one. :(